# center a google map marker on jhipster application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3

actually I work in a Jhispter APP, I have implemented a NG-MAP tag and a MARKER tag into to show a location and this runs but my problem is that I am not able to center my point MARKER in the middle of div and I don't get it

I use CENTER attribute in NG-MAP tag and nothing...

```
<ng-map zoom="15" center="{{vm.terreno0101.latitud}},{{vm.terreno0101.longitud}}">
                    <marker position="{{vm.terreno0101.latitud}},{{vm.terreno0101.longitud}}" title="Supplier Location" centered="true"></marker>
                </ng-map>
```

Comment: The member name is `latitud`? Is ng-map some third party angular directive?

Comment: i don't know what you mean, please could  you be a little more specific?

Comment: Not a JHipster question, this is only about angular and google map. You should provide the HTML and css of the container div

Comment: I don't have css styles for the div, I've tried in the plunker page and i didn't need any style, maybe could need add a lib but I doubt it because I've implemented ng-map lib, across bower installer